# john deere sx75

Tags: troubleshooting, tractor

My SX75 was moving when it stopped. It does not move forward or backwards. The clutch pedal feels fine. If i put it in gear with the tractor off it cannot be pushed forward or backwards (trans engaged).

How is the power transferred from the engine through the rear wheels? Is there a belt in the drive train? How do I gain access to this area?

Could not find a service manual or a diagram.

Jim

Answer (score 5):

Your mower has a transaxle.

It's belt driven and has a primary belt that resembles a fan belt for a car.

- [Here is an online resource.](http://manuals.deere.com/cceomview/OMM133763_F7/Output/OMM133763_F712.html)

Search the URL with "Removing Primary Drive Belt (SX85)" and it will give a diagram and instructions on removing and replacing the drive belt, if that's the issue.  The manual covers many other areas as well.